# Combination and Permutation problems

Tags: permutations, combinations

Can someone help me with this problem?

In one set of parallel lines there are *m* lines; in another set of lines which are parallel to each other but not to the first set, there are *n* lines. How many parallelograms are formed?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: choose any 2 of the m and any 2 of the n to form your parallelogram

Comment: Can you please give me a hint what to do first?

Comment: Try drawing some pictures for small values of $m$ and $n$.  See if a pattern emerges.

Comment: Is it like m(m-1)n(n-1) pattern?

Comment: $\left(\begin{array}{c}m\\ 2\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ 2\end{array}\right) = \frac{m(m-1)}2\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

All the ways in which you can choose two diagonally opposite vertices $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$, such that
$$
\left( {1 \le a < b \le m} \right) \wedge \left( {1 \le c < d \le n} \right)
$$

That is, in
$$
\left( {\left( {m - 1} \right)+\left( {m - 2} \right)+ \cdots +1} \right)\; \cdot \;\left( {\left( {n - 1} \right)+\left( {n - 2} \right)+ \cdots +1} \right) = {m \choose 2}{n \choose 2}
$$
ways

Comment: There should be a + between all those sub cases (m-1) + (m-2) ...

Comment: The answer is 1/4 *m*m-1*n*n-1  I don't know where the 1/4 comes from

Comment: @Rick: you are right, my bad lapse: thanks for signalling! I amended the answer.